# C++ boost thread: having a worker thread pause and unpause based on mutexes/conditions using a concurrent queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex

I am fairly new to multi-threaded programming, so please forgive my possibly imprecise question. Here is my problem:

I have a function processing data and generating lots of objects of the same type. This is done iterating in several nested loops, so it would be practical to just do all iterations, save these objects in some container and then work on that container in interfacing code doing the next steps. However, I have to create millions of these objects which would blow up the memory usage. These constraints are mainly due to external factors I cannot control.

Generating only a certain amount of data would be ideal, but breaking out of the loops and restarting later at the same point is also impractical. My idea was to do the processing in a separate thread which would be paused after n iterations and resumed once all n objects are completely processed, then resuming, doing n next iterations and so on until all iterations are done. It is important to wait until the thread has done all n iterations, so both threads would not really run in parallel.

This is where my problems begin: How do I do the mutex locking properly here? My approaches produce boost::lock_errors. Here is some code to show what I want to do:

```
boost::recursive_mutex bla;
boost::condition_variable_any v1;
boost::condition_variable_any v2;
boost::recursive_mutex::scoped_lock lock(bla);
int got_processed = 0;
const int n = 10;

void ProcessNIterations() {
  got_processed = 0;
  // have some mutex or whatever unlocked here so that the worker thread can 
  // start or resume. 
  // my idea: have some sort of mutex lock that unlocks here and a condition
  // variable v1 that is notified while the thread is waiting for that.
  lock.unlock();
  v1.notify_one();

  // while the thread is working to do the iterations this function should wait
  // because there is no use to proceed until the n iterations are done
  // my idea: have another condition v2 variable that we wait for here and lock
  // afterwards so the thread is blocked/paused
  while (got_processed < n) {
    v2.wait(lock);
  }
}

void WorkerThread() {
  int counter = 0;
  // wait for something to start
  // my idea: acquire a mutex lock here that was locked elsewhere before and 
  // wait for ProcessNIterations() to unlock it so this can start
  boost::recursive_mutex::scoped_lock internal_lock(bla);

  for (;;) {
    for (;;) {
      // here do the iterations
      counter++;
      std::cout << "iteration #" << counter << std::endl;
      got_processed++;

      if (counter >= n) {
        // we've done n iterations; pause here
        // my idea: unlock the mutex, notify v2
        internal_lock.unlock();
        v2.notify_one();

        while (got_processed > 0) {
          // when ProcessNIterations() is called again, resume here
          // my idea: wait for v1 reacquiring the mutex again
          v1.wait(internal_lock);
        }
        counter = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  boost::thread mythread(WorkerThread);

  ProcessNIterations();
  ProcessNIterations();

  while (true) {}
}
```

The above code fails after doing 10 iterations in the line `v2.wait(lock);` with the following message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >'
  what():  boost::lock_error
```

How do I do this properly? If this is the way to go, how do I avoid lock_errors?

**EDIT:** I solved it using a concurrent queue like discussed [here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html). This queue also has a maximum size after which a `push` will simply wait until at least one element has been `pop`ed. Therefore, the producer worker can simply go on filling this queue and the rest of the code can `pop` entries as it is suitable. No mutex locking needs to be done outside the queue. The queue is here:

```
template<typename Data>
class concurrent_queue
{
private:
  std::queue<Data> the_queue;
  mutable boost::mutex the_mutex;
  boost::condition_variable the_condition_variable;
  boost::condition_variable the_condition_variable_popped;
  int max_size_;
public:
  concurrent_queue(int max_size=-1) : max_size_(max_size) {}

  void push(const Data& data) {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(the_mutex);

    while (max_size_ > 0 && the_queue.size() >= max_size_) {
      the_condition_variable_popped.wait(lock);
    }

    the_queue.push(data);
    lock.unlock();
    the_condition_variable.notify_one();
  }

  bool empty() const {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(the_mutex);
    return the_queue.empty();
  }

  bool wait_and_pop(Data& popped_value) {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(the_mutex);
    bool locked = true;
    if (the_queue.empty()) {
      locked = the_condition_variable.timed_wait(lock, boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
    }

    if (locked && !the_queue.empty()) {
      popped_value=the_queue.front();
      the_queue.pop();
      the_condition_variable_popped.notify_one();
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  int size() {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(the_mutex);
    return the_queue.size();
  }
};
```

Comment: You need to look up [condition_variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_signal.html).

Comment: @LokiAstari, +1 I didnt see your comment until after I submit my answer :) Like they say, great minds think alike ;)

Comment: Condition variables were my idea as well. However, somehow it does not work how I want it to because boost throws lock_errors. I will try to give some small example which shows this.

Answer (score 1):

This could be implemented using conditional variables. Once you've performed N iterations, you call wait() on the condition variable, and when the objects are processed in another thread, call signal() on the condition variable to unblock the other thread that is blocked on the condition variable.

Comment: As can be seen above, condition variables do not really work as expected. Obviously I did something wrong.

Comment: @FlorianKruse, try changing the order of the call to notify() and the mutex unlock.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want some sort of finite capacity queue list or stack in conjunction with a condition variable. When the queue is full, the producer thread waits on the condition variable, and any time a consumer thread removes an element from the queue, it signals the condition variable. That would allow the producer to wake up and fill the queue again. If you really wanted to process N elements at a time, then have the workers signal only when there's capacity in the queue for N elements, rather then every time they pull an item out of the queue.

Comment: Having a consumer thread run in parallel is a much more elegant idea. However, for some reasons (most of them outside my reach), it seems more practical to produce N objects and then further process them afterwards. But I will consider the option and check if it's feasible.